# How to create a transformation matrix from a scale and a translation, using Eigen3?

Tags: c++, eigen3

I am stumped on how to create a simple transformation matrix.

I have the following C++ code:

```
  static constexpr float pos_scale = 2 * size / iside;
  static constexpr std::array<float, 2> pos_translation = { -size, -size };
```

Unfortunately, the `pos_translation` needs to be a `std::array` because you can't make an `Eigen::Vector2f` constexpr.

Then I have a vector:

```
Vector2i xy;
```

That will be filled with some data.
I want to convert `xy` to a `Vector2f` by converting it to homogeneous coordinates, multiplying it with a transformation matrix and then dropping the homogeneous coordinates again.

The transformation matrix is declared as

```
Matrix3f xy_to_pos;
```

at least, I think that is the right type to use?

My question is, how can I initialize `xy_to_pos` from `pos_scale` (which has to be applied first: first the scale then the translation) and `pos_translation`?

And once I have `xy_to_pos` how would I use it to convert `xy` to `Vector2f pos`?

I tried all kinds of things, like

```
Matrix3f xy_to_pos = Matrix3f::Identity() * Eigen::Scaling(pos_scale) * Eigen::Translation2f(pos_translation[0], pos_translation[1]);
```

but nothing compiles, and the compile errors don't help. I Googled for this too of course, but couldn't find an example that helped.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out:

```
static constexpr float pos_scale = 2 * size / iside;
static constexpr std::array<float, 2> pos_translation = { -size, -size };

Transform<float, 2, Affine> const xy_to_pos =
    Transform<float, 2, Affine>{Transform<float, 2, Affine>::Identity()}
    .translate(Vector2f{pos_translation.data()})
    .scale(pos_scale);

Vector2i xy(2, 3); // Or whatever

Vector2f pos = xy_to_pos * xy.cast<float>();
```

Comment: The `.colwise().homogeneous()` should not be necessary and there should be some shorter ways to construct the `Transform` object ...

Comment: @chtz Clearly I am new to Eigen ;).  If you can improve my answer then please do! Or add your own answer. I really hate it that it requires this much text to create an Identity Transform matrix, only to immediately convert it to a translation matrix.

Comment: Thanks - you were right that the `.colwise().homogeneous()` weren't needed. I removed that.